# Ubuntu will often crash, but only during the first few minutes after booting

Tags: 18.04, crash, 19.10

Ubuntu will often crash within the first few minutes after booting.

If it survives the first few minutes - I've never seen it crash.

The crash:

The screen will freeze for ~5 seconds

Then the monitor, keyboard, and mouse lights will all go off as if the computer was turned off - at the same time the computer fans go up to 100%

If I don't use the computer for the first few minutes (touch the mouse or keyboard) it seems like it's much less likely to crash.

Maybe 50% chance of crashing if I move the mouse or try to do anything on the computer during the first few minutes.

Maybe 10% chance of crashing if I don't touch the computer for the first few minutes.

This has happened on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 19.10

AMD Ryzen 5 2600

AMD RX 570

16GB RAM

I have no idea where to start diagnosing this issue, any help is appreciated

Update:

https://gist.github.com/RickAndTired/2593db2f1384be7426f0b6a92eed2660

Here is the log of the crash

Lines 1-5 and 9-18 are in red

Comment: Note the exact time of a freeze. After reboot, look in /var/log/syslog for events that occurred at that time. Also look in /var/crash for a newly-generated crashfile.

Comment: If this a desktop or laptop? Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the last part of the system logs of the 1st previous  boot (`-b -1`).

Comment: @user535733 and waltinator
Thanks - I think I found some errors in those, need to do some testing to see if that's the problem. Looks like a tsc, bios, or pcie issue.

heynnema - Desktop
https://gist.github.com/RickAndTired/1fb1dfdde99c9e2eb5c558b5215ce2b9